# How to detect location and size of tab header in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am still new to javaFX. In my code I need to get location and size of tab header, but I can't find any property or function which return its size or location.

Comment: Just wondering why you would want this information. Perhaps there is a better way to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand your question properly, but generally you can use the [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) function to get the [.tab-header-area CSS selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane) which is actually a `StackPane`.

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
tabPane.getTabs().addAll(new Tab("Tab1"), new Tab("Tab2"), new Tab("Tab3"));

Button b = new Button("Get header");
b.setOnAction((e) -> {  
    StackPane headerArea = (StackPane) tabPane.lookup(".tab-header-area");
    System.out.println("Coordinates relatively to Scene: " + headerArea.localToScene(headerArea.getBoundsInLocal()));
});
```

*The output*

```
Coordinates relatively to Scene: BoundingBox [minX:0.0, minY:0.0, minZ:0.0, width:500.0, height:29.0, depth:0.0, maxX:500.0, maxY:29.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

If you want to get the information about the individual tabs:

```
Set<Node> tabs = tabPane.lookupAll(".tab");
for (Node node : tabs) {
    System.out.println("Coordinates relatively to Scene: " + node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal()));
}
```

*and the output*

```
Coordinates relatively to Scene: BoundingBox [minX:5.0, minY:5.0, minZ:0.0, width:54.0, height:24.0, depth:0.0, maxX:59.0, maxY:29.0, maxZ:0.0]
Coordinates relatively to Scene: BoundingBox [minX:59.0, minY:5.0, minZ:0.0, width:38.0, height:24.0, depth:0.0, maxX:97.0, maxY:29.0, maxZ:0.0]
Coordinates relatively to Scene: BoundingBox [minX:97.0, minY:5.0, minZ:0.0, width:38.0, height:24.0, depth:0.0, maxX:135.0, maxY:29.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

I have used the [localToScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene-javafx.geometry.Bounds-) function with the parameter of the [local bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInLocal--) of the `StackPane` to get the coordinates relative to the `Scene`.

**Note:** Lookup is not guaranteed to work, until CSS has been applied to the `Scene`.