# JavaFX: How to fit TabPane to its content?

Tags: javafx, layout

I would like to make a TabPane fit its size to its content.
I am currently doing it with the code below:

```
    Node viewRoot = ...;

    Tab tab = new Tab("tabName");

    if (viewRoot instanceof Region) {
        Region region = (Region) viewRoot;

        StackPane tabHeaderArea = (StackPane) tabPane.lookup(".tab-header-area");
        double tabHeaderHeight = tabHeaderArea.getHeight();

        tabPane.widthProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> region.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue()));
        tabPane.heightProperty()
                .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> region.setPrefHeight(newValue.doubleValue() - tabHeaderHeight));
    }
```

However I do not particularly like this solution because of (a) the cast of node to Region, and (b) relying on the lookup to get the height of the tab header area.

Is there any cleaner way to achieve the same?

Disclaimer: The snippet to get the tab header size is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366096/how-to-detect-location-and-size-of-tab-header-in-javafx). Unfortunately my reputation is not sufficient to comment on that post.